# How to continue with nested for loops with a "zsh: no matches found" error?

Tags: shell, zsh

I have many video files that are split by Day, Camera Channel, Event time range (`YYYY-MM-DD/VIDEOCHANNELNUMBER-EVENTIMERANGE.mp4`)

```
/2021-07-03/ch2_main_20210703074010_20210703074154.mp4
/2021-07-03/ch2_main_20210703074156_20210703074357.mp4
/2021-07-03/ch2_main_20210703074446_20210703074537.mp4
/2021-07-03/ch2_main_20210703074618_20210703075119.mp4
/2021-07-03/ch2_main_20210703075153_20210703075312.mp4
/2021-07-03/ch2_main_20210703075337_20210703080422.mp4
```

I want to merge these clips by Day and Camera Channel only (ie `/2021-04-03-CH1.mp4`)

My process is:

1. Iterate through each date folder (`for VIDEODIR in */`)
2. Within each folder, iterate through each channel number (`for VIDEOCHANNELNUMBER in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do`)
3. for each channel number, find all the video files to combine (`for f in $VIDEODIR/ch$VIDEOCHANNELNUMBER*.mp4 ; do`)
4. FFMPEG combine and save this file into the root directory (`ffmpeg -i $VIDEOLIST -c copy "$DATE-CH$VIDEOCHANNELNUMBER.mp4"`)
5. When successful delete the directory of all the original clips. (`if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then rm $VIDEODIR -r fi`)

I'm stuck because Step 2 errors out when there are no matches due to that video channel being offline during that day for some reason. (`zsh: no matches found: /2021-07-03/ch1*.mp4`). This breaks the entire loop, rather than skip and continue.

Comment: Aside: Instead of `ffmpeg...; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ...`, just run `if ffmpeg ...; then`. See [Why is testing `$?` to see if a command succeeded or not an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: Anyhow -- _in bash_, what you're looking for would be `shopt -s nullglob`. In zsh, there's a modifier that does the same thing, but I don't know it offhand.

Comment: I think the _no matches found_ belongs to step 3, not step 2. You could write the loop as `for f in $VIDEODIR/ch$VIDEOCHANNELNUMBER*.mp4(N)`. This would make the loop being skipped if there are no mp4 files.